# How can update attributes for existing registered user in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

I registered one user with some attributes using ABAC features with Node.js SDK but after some operation, I want to update its attributes, is it possible to update?

I found how can we modify existing identity attributes using command but how can I do with Node.js SDK?

Here is the link:
http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#modifying-an-identity

Please help how can I do this with Node.js SDK.

Comment: I have not tried it, but it looks like you can use the identity service provided by the sdk to send new register request, and specify the new attributes the same was as through the cli - https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/IdentityService.html#update__anchor. Just resend the original request or rebuild it with the updated attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through using IdentityService. You can easily change attributes by update method. The code is provided here. https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-572?focusedCommentId=46030&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-46030